# NLTK WordNetLemmatizer fails to process nested tags in intents.json file

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, nltk

When I try to batch process a 32k rows intents.json file with multiple tags using nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer class, python exits with no trace back even using the debugger.

this is the function where python fails:

```
def setupTrainingData(self):
        try:

            words = []
            classes = []
            documents = []
            ignoreLetters = [
                '?', '!', '.', ',', ")", "(", ":", ";", "&", ">", "<", "=", "'"]
            for intent in self.intents["intents"]:
                for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
                    wordList = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
                    words.extend(wordList)
                    documents.append((wordList, intent["tag"]))
                    classes.extend(intent["tag"])

            words = [self.lemmatizer.lemmatize(word)
                                 for word in words if word not in ignoreLetters]

            words = sorted(set(words))
            classes = sorted(set(classes))

            pickle.dump(words, open(f"{self.settings.PKL_DIR}/words.pkl", "wb"))
            pickle.dump(classes, open(f"{self.settings.PKL_DIR}/classes.pkl", "wb"))

            training = []
            outputEmpty = [0] * len(classes)
            batch = 0

            lock = threading.Lock()
            results = []

            def process_batch(batch_documents):
                nonlocal training
                nonlocal results

                batch_training = []

                for document in batch_documents:
                    bag = []
                    wordPatterns = document[0]
                    wordPatterns = [self.lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower())
                                                        for word in wordPatterns]
                    for word in words:
                        bag.append(1) if word in wordPatterns else bag.append(0)

                    outputRow = list(outputEmpty)
                    if isinstance(document[1], list):
                        for tag in document[1]:
                            if tag in classes:
                                outputRow[classes.index(tag)] = 1
                    else:
                        if document[1] in classes:
                            outputRow[classes.index(document[1])] = 1

                    batch_training.append(bag + outputRow)

                with lock:
                    training.extend(batch_training)
                    results.append(True)

            batch_size = 1000
            num_batches = len(documents) // batch_size
            extra_docs = len(documents) % batch_size

            threads = []

            for i in range(num_batches):
                start = i * batch_size
                end = start + batch_size
                batch_documents = documents[start:end]

                t = threading.Thread(target=process_batch, args=(batch_documents,))
                threads.append(t)
                t.start()

            if extra_docs > 0:
                batch_documents = documents[-extra_docs:]
                t = threading.Thread(target=process_batch, args=(batch_documents,))
                threads.append(t)
                t.start()

            for t in threads:
                t.join()

            while len(results) < num_batches + (extra_docs > 0):
                pass

            random.shuffle(training)
            training = np.array(training)

            self.trainX = training[:, :len(words)]
            self.trainY = training[:, len(words):]

            print(f"X {self.trainX}", f"Y {self.trainY}")
            print(f"LEN X {len(self.trainX)}", f"LEN Y {len(self.trainY)}")

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

I have versions without threading as well as lowering the rows to just 10k but the function just exits with no feedback. I am not an expert on machine learning so I am unsure what is going wrong here